redis connection problem (I think it's a version mismatch)
I wanted to learn Redis this time, so I was testing using Redis and Springboot web controller to put the values in Redis.
But it works well in the spring boot, but when I checked the redis through Windows PowerShell, there were no keys inside.
At first, I wondered if the spring boot and redis were not connected, but when I checked, it was connected again.
I thought I should watch it on the GUI, so I downloaded and used a program called "another redis desktop manager," and here I can see that I put the value in the spring boot.
I checked the info to see what's different, and it seems that each other's version is different.
I think this is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it
I'm using application.yml in spring boot, and I'm using 3.3.3 in the spring boot version.
I've done pretty much everything I can ask ChatGPT...
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

Can you post your Java/Spring code? Are you mapping Java entities to Redis Hashes and using Spring Repositories? If so, you'll need:
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories

As part of your Spring Boot configuration code.
